# Two TextViews clashing in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make two TextViews that will be on the same row. The first one should be left aligned and the second one right aligned, when one of them becomes to big the first one (the left aligned should go on new row). I was able to make the first one to go on new line when the second TextView (the right aligned one) became too big but the problem is that it doesn't display the whole information from it. So anyone has any ideas. I'd like it to be with RelativeLayout but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should play with `android:layout_weight` to acheive this , this is how it should be :

```
<LinearLayout .....
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="left"
     android:text="TextView Left"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:text="TextView Right"
     android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks man, but the width of both should be wrap_content because if it's like that if one is longer than the other but they can fill the row the one that is longer goes on two rows and wrap_content for width fixed the problem.

Comment: no ,the width should be 0dp , because the weight will divide the width of the parent layout between the two TextViews , so the code above will work

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting the two textviews into a linearlayout, set the layout_weight="1" on both textviews and their layout_width="0".

Answer (score 0):

give weight = 1 for both text views....

if it does't work....change relative layout to linear layout or table row and give weight to 1 for both text view

Answer (score 0):

Put your TextViews in LinearLayout and set layout_weight=1. it will solve your problem.